Caching when using a loop in PL/pgSQL
I am using PostGIS to calculate length of interactions between two types of employees. I am performing the same set of operations for each area id. Here is my code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(areaid_array character varying[], d_date date, start_time__ timestamp without time zone, end_time__ timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(area_id uuid, "createdAt_" timestamp without time zone, "updatedAt_" timestamp without time zone, "ID_" character varying, parent_imei character varying, child_imei character varying, parent_ping_time timestamp without time zone, child_ping_time timestamp without time zone, maxima timestamp without time zone, minima timestamp without time zone, "interactionID" character varying, interaction_type character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
DECLARE i integer := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(areaid_array, 1) LOOP
        RETURN QUERY with pings as (  
          select  * from -- ================= SELECTING Parent INFO 
          (select p.imei, 
                  st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
                  "generatedAt" as t, 
                  p."ID" as u_ping_id 
            from  campaign_pings p 
            where "generatedAt" + interval '5 hours' between start_time__ and end_time__
              and p.imei in (/*multiple left joins*/)
          ) u 
          left join ( -- ================= SELECTING child INFO 
            SELECT p.imei, 
                   p."ID" as a_ping_id, 
                   st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
                   "generatedAt" as t 
            FROM campaign_pings p 
            where "generatedAt"+ interval '5 hours' between start_time__ and end_time__
              and p.imei in (/*multiple left joins*/)
          ) a on ST_DWithin(u."geom", a."geom", 30) 
          and a.t BETWEEN u.t - INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          and u.t + INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          where 
          a.imei is not null
      )/*more code to calculate length of continuous interactions in minutes*/;
    END LOOP;
END $function$;

So essentially, I am performing the same set of operations for each area id. Is there a way to make use of caching here to reduce execution time? I mean to enforce the use of cache.
P.S - here is the full function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(areaid_array character varying[], d_date date, start_time__ timestamp without time zone, end_time__ timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(area_id uuid, "createdAt_" timestamp without time zone, "updatedAt_" timestamp without time zone, "ID_" character varying, parent_imei character varying, child_imei character varying, parent_ping_time timestamp without time zone, child_ping_time timestamp without time zone, maxima timestamp without time zone, minima timestamp without time zone, "interactionID" character varying, interaction_type character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    i integer := 1;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(areaid_array, 1) LOOP
        RETURN QUERY 
       
        --SELECT areaid_array[i], d_date;
       
       with pings as ( -- ================= SELECTING JOINED data with join conditions -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
        select 
          u."imei" as u_imei, 
          a."imei" as a_imei, 
          u.t as u_ping_time, 
          a.t as a_ping_time, 
          u_ping_id, 
          a_ping_id 
        from 

(-- ================= SELECTING Parent INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            select 
              p.imei, 
              st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t, 
              p."ID" as u_ping_id 
            from 
              campaign_pings p 
            
              
              where --"createdAt"::date = d_date--d_date
              
              "generatedAt" + interval '5 hours' between start_time__ and end_time__
                       
              and 
              
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_info csi on csi."campaignStaffID"=staff."ID" and csi."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_info csi2 where csi2."campaignStaffID" = csi."campaignStaffID" and csi2.date <= d_date)
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<=d_date)
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<=d_date)
                  left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID"
                  where 
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = areaid_array[i]::uuid --'0156276d-29e3-4da8-bc76-39d6ad3bf1f6' 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = '38eb4157-c0e8-4334-ad79-9801610c4ab8' -- UCMO ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and ((csi.number is null) or (csi.number <> '0'))
                  and d_date between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."catchupEndDate"  
              )
          ) u 
          left join ( -- ================= SELECTING child INFO [imei, geom, generatedAt, pingID] -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= -- ================= 
            SELECT 
              p.imei, 
              p."ID" as a_ping_id, 
              st_transform(p."geoJson", 32643) as geom, 
              "generatedAt" as t 
            FROM 
              campaign_pings p 
              
              where --"createdAt"::date = d_date --d_date
              
              "generatedAt"+ interval '5 hours' between start_time__ and end_time__
              
              and 
                            
              p.imei in (
                select 
                  assets."IMEI" 
                from 
                  campaign_staff staff 
                  left join campaign_staff_assets csa on csa."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and csa."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_staff_assets cs2 where cs2."campaignStaffID"= csa."campaignStaffID" and cs2.date<=d_date)
                  left join campaign_area_assets caa on caa."assetID" = csa."assetID" 
                  and caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = csa."campaignScopeID" 
                  left join assets assets on assets."ID" = caa."assetID" 
                  left join staff_type staff_type ON staff_type."ID" = staff."staffTypeID"
                  left join campaign_asset_status cas  on cas."campaignStaffID" = staff."ID" and cas."date" = (select max(date) from campaign_asset_status cas2 where cas2."campaignStaffID"= cas."campaignStaffID" and cas2.date<=d_date)
                  left join campaign_scope cs on cs."areaID" = caa."campaignScopeAreaID"
                  
                  where 
                  
                  caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = areaid_array[i]::uuid 
                  and assets."IMEI" is not null 
                  and staff_type."ID" = '93313048-4e75-4e91-9bcd-44897a6df7c7' -- AIC ID
                  and (cas.status is null or cas.status  <> 'DeployedWoPhone')
                  and d_date between cs."campaignStartDate" and cs."catchupEndDate"
                  
              )
          ) a on ST_DWithin(u."geom", a."geom", 30) 
          and a.t BETWEEN u.t - INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          and u.t + INTERVAL '30 seconds' 
          where 
          a.imei is not null
      )
      
      
      
      

,
ranked_interactions AS (
    SELECT 
        u_imei,
        a_imei,
        a_ping_time +interval '5 hours' as a_ping_time,
        u_ping_time+interval '5 hours' as u_ping_time,
        (LEAD(u_ping_time) OVER (PARTITION BY u_imei, a_imei ORDER BY u_ping_time)) + interval '5 hours' AS next_parent_time,-- OG
            
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u_imei, a_imei ORDER BY u_ping_time) AS interaction_rank
    FROM 
        pings 
)
,
dummy as (
select *,next_parent_time-u_ping_time as time_diff from ranked_interactions 
 
)
,
periods as (
select *, case when time_diff < interval '3 minute' then 'normal'
when time_diff >= interval '3 minute' then 'abnormal'
end as periods
from dummy )

,

 ranked_data AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    LEAD(a_ping_time) OVER (PARTITION BY u_imei, a_imei ORDER BY a_ping_time) AS start_time,
    
    max(a_ping_time) over (PARTITION BY u_imei, a_imei) as max_time
    
  FROM periods 
),

f_data AS (
  SELECT
    *
     
  FROM ranked_data
  
  WHERE periods = 'abnormal' 
  
  
  union 
  
  select * FROM ranked_data
  where interaction_rank=1 
)
,
format as (
select *,lead(a_ping_time) over (PARTITION BY u_imei, a_imei) as duration_calc
from f_data 

)
,


results as (
select *,
duration_calc-start_time as duration from format
where interaction_rank <> 1 and duration_calc is not null 

union 

select *, 

-- duration_calc - a_ping_time  as duration from format 
duration_calc - start_time  as duration from format---changedcode

where interaction_rank  = 1

union 

select *, max_time - start_time as duration from format 
where duration_calc  is null 

order by u_imei,a_imei,interaction_rank 
)
,
results_filtered as (
select * from results where duration>= interval '3 minute'
)

,
--parent_imei, child_imei, parent_ping_time, child_ping_time, maxima, minima, "interactionID", "forUcmo"

adding as (
select 
--null as created_at,null as updated_at,null as id,
--results_filtered.*,
*,
case when interaction_rank = 1 and periods='normal'

then start_time - interval '1 minute'

else start_time 

end as start_time_final from results_filtered)


select areaid_array[i]::uuid as area_id_,

NOW()::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone as createdat,NOW()::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE as updatedat,

CONCAT(adding.start_time_final, '-', adding.a_imei, '-', adding.u_imei,'-',NOW())::varchar as id,

--adding.created_at,

--adding.updated_at,

--adding.id,

adding.u_imei::varchar as parent_imei_ ,

adding.a_imei::varchar as child_imei_,

adding.u_ping_time as parent_ping_time_,

adding.a_ping_time as child_ping_time_,

case when adding.interaction_rank=1 and adding.periods='normal'

then adding.start_time_final+duration+interval '1 minute' 

else adding.start_time_final+duration

end as maxima_,


adding.start_time_final as minima_, 

--adding.u_imei+adding.a_imei+duration as "interactionID_",

CONCAT(adding.u_imei, '-', adding.a_imei, '-', duration)::varchar as "interactionID_",

'UA'::varchar as interaction_type

--adding.duration,adding.start_time_final 

from adding


;

       
       
       
       
       
    END LOOP;
END
$function$
;


A PL/pgSQL loop that's re-running the same query for a bunch of things can usually be rewritten into a single regular SQL query, outperforming it - mostly because PostgreSQL will be able to optimise for you. It's hard to tell how you'd go about that here because the code is too heavily redacted and you cut out the part where you use the i you're looping over. You're not supposed to show some code of yours, the point here is to present a reproducible example.

As to "caching", if there are identical CTEs/subqueries that you repeat between each iteration of the loop, you can write those to a temp table once, before entering the loop, then let the loop only run the varying part of the query, referring to the pre-fetched common parts without having to re-collect them each time.

@Zegarek would cursor/fetch commands help here?

That's for pagination - I don't see how it fits into your problem/question. It's hard to discuss code you're not showing or saying what and why it is supposed to be doing.

@Zegarek I have added the entire function to the post, please let me know what you think!

The example isn't reproducible so I'm just compiling a bunch of comments into a sort-of-an-answer to the underlying question of how to speed this up, plus some random tips, in no particular order:

You don't need to use an int iterator, then subscript the array. You can iterate over the array directly

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(areaid_array uuid[]
--...
DECLARE current_areaid uuid;
BEGIN FOREACH current_areaid IN ARRAY areaid_array LOOP RETURN QUERY 
--...
WHERE caa."campaignScopeAreaID" = current_areaid


Unless it's your intention to get an empty fields between consecutive separators in your concatenated string when one of the fields is a null, use concat_ws(). It lets you specify the separator once, and then just list the fields to be separated by it.

CONCAT_WS('-',adding.start_time_final, adding.a_imei, adding.u_imei,NOW())::varchar as id,


You might want to reorder your joins and conditions. It seems that the size of campaign_staff drives the imei list subquery, and then you filter that down afterwards. You might want to make sure it's driven by the smallest table and that you filter things out as early as possible. To an extent, Postgres will try to rearrange your joins and conditions attempting to do that automatically, but with this much stuff that might not be effective.
You're joining to entire campaign_staff_info, campaign_staff_assets and campaign_asset_status, then filter that down using a subquery from that same table. You could just as well join directly to the subquery and do your filtering in it. You could also try to pre-fetch those max(date)s along with the csi."campaignStaffID" and later join to that pre-fetched, static temp table - if holding on to the additional column in a not fully filtered set isn't that much of an expense, you might get some performance by doing it once ahead of the loop instead of repeating twice in each loop.
This function forces the query to be sequentially re-ran. You can just as easily make it a plain SQL function accepting just a single areaid, then let another regular SQL function wrap it to allow for accepting an array, just to unnest() it and call the primary function for each element. PostgreSQL will likely do a better job distributing the work, not necessarily stuffing it all into a queue, where each area has to wait for the previous ones to finish. It might even distribute some parallel workers and evaluate all queries for each areaid, all at the same time.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(p_areaid uuid, d_date date, start_time__ timestamp without time zone, end_time__ timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS TABLE(area_id uuid, "createdAt_" timestamp without time zone, "updatedAt_" timestamp without time zone, "ID_" character varying, parent_imei character varying, child_imei character varying, parent_ping_time timestamp without time zone, child_ping_time timestamp without time zone, maxima timestamp without time zone, minima timestamp without time zone, "interactionID" character varying, interaction_type character varying)
LANGUAGE SQL AS $function$
with pings as (
--...
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(p_areaid_array uuid[], d_date date, start_time__ timestamp without time zone, end_time__ timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS TABLE(area_id uuid, "createdAt_" timestamp without time zone, "updatedAt_" timestamp without time zone, "ID_" character varying, parent_imei character varying, child_imei character varying, parent_ping_time timestamp without time zone, child_ping_time timestamp without time zone, maxima timestamp without time zone, minima timestamp without time zone, "interactionID" character varying, interaction_type character varying)
LANGUAGE SQL AS $function$
SELECT interactions_looped_ucmo_aic(p_areaid, d_date, start_time__, end_time__)
FROM UNNEST(p_areaid_array)p_areaid
$function$;


Rewriting this as a regular SQL function removes the PL/pgSQL overhead, plus it enables SQL function body inlining, which can speed things up further. Plus the improved automatic optimisability mentioned earlier.


thanks so much, may you have a happy and blessed life!

btw I tried implementing the regular SQL functions, but they did not result in a query speed up. It seems parallelism did not kick in. What I am doing instead is breaking down the area id array into two chunks, and making two simultaneous function calls with each chunk - this appoximately halves the total time taken.

can you please let me know if you think PREPARED statements would be useful here?

@Maverick Distributing the work on client side is another good idea if the db refuses to do that on its own. If switching to plain SQL doesn't speed anything up, it might be because compared to the total execution time this costs, the difference is imperceptible. Still, there's nothing you do in there that strictly requires PL/pgSQL, so there's no reason to add that cost, however small. If you run this a lot, I'd stick with a plain SQL version or even make it a prepared statement, then stuff this into a worker pool and let it distribute the array among workers, each requesting one areaid.

@Maverick Yes, I was in the middle of pointing out exactly that, when you added the prepared statement question. It'll allow PostgreSQL to cache and re-use the query plan, so each worker doesn't have to go through query planning stage.
